# Angular JS implement Search

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with multiple fields.  How do I implement search using angularjs? For example I have the following page:

```
<pre>
    <input name="title">
    <input name="isbn">
    <input name="author">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">

    <!-- list the book information -->
    Title     Author     ISBN
</pre>
```

I want the bottom list to display based on user input on the search fields from the server. **Note:**The user can input on mutiple fields. How do I accomplish the search when the user clicks the submit button?

Do I need to write one submit method.  If so how can I get the values and do the query depending on the field is left blank or not?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear where the collection is. Are you asking "How do I send the server the right information to do this search for me?", or "The server has sent me a collection of books, how do I apply a client-side filter to the collection?"

Answer (score 0):

If your using angularJS you don't need a submit it will do it asynchronously.  Just add an ng-model to your input and filter the results based on that.  Something like this:

```
    <input name="title" ng-model="title">
    <input name="isbn" ng-model="isbn">
    <input name="author" ng-model="author>

<div filter: title | filter:isbn | filter:author >
   Title     Author     ISBN
</div>
```

Comment: This either assumes that the data can be requested over http up front without any form data being needed to make the request or it assumes the API is lightweight enough to make an http request on every key press , if either of these assumptions is correct then this approach is ok but detail is scant as it doesn't address input validation +1 for approach taken in listing results, -1 for lack of effort in relation to form elements

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<form name='fred' novalidate='novalidate' ng-submit='submitFunc()'>

  <input name='username' required='required' pattern='a-z'>
  <input type='email'>
  <input type='submit' ng-disabled='fred.$invalid'>

</form>
```

In your submitFunc you would do an $http request to get your data and filter it and then store the results in an array and do an ng-repeat in the view below the form to iterate over your results

Answer (score 0):

A basic implementation should look like this:

the code:

```
app.controller('SampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var search = function() {
    yourAjaxMethod({author: $scope.author, isbn: $scope.isbn, title: $scope.title}).then(function(list) {
      $scope.list = list;
    });
  }
  $scope.$watch('author', search);
  $scope.$watch('isbn', search);
  $scope.$watch('title', search);
  // the init loading
  search();
}])
```

The markup:

```
<pre>
  <input name="title">
  <input name="isbn">
  <input name="author">
  <br/>


  <!-- list the book information -->
  <table>
   <tr>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Author</th>
     <th>ISBN</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="book in list">
     <td ng-bind="book.title"></td>
     <td ng-bind="book.author"></td>
     <td ng-bind="book.isbn"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```